# Displaying the Global Navigation bar which has disappeared

Tags: navigation, html5

I am learning html5 whilst developing a SharePoint 2013 site.  I added code to remove the page title of the pages but now the Global Navigation bar has disappeared.  I can see it the Navigation settings and have removed all the code that I had added but the bar remains hidden.  Is there some simple code that will turn it back on.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Post the code that was you added?

Comment: <style type="text/css">
#pageContentTitle {
display: none !important;
}

Comment: It should come back since you removed that code..try to refresh page using Ctr+F5. If you want to hide page title then use #pageTitle{ display: none !important; }.

Comment: Hi it displays it for a few seconds and then hides it again.  What is the opposite of none - how can I use the same code to turn it back on again.  I had added it in the script editor on a couple of pages so perhaps there is some residual code.  I have gone through all the pages and there doesn't appear to be any of this code there though.

Comment: if you want to hide page title from all pages then its better to add css in master page.

Comment: Thanks so much - just seen your comment but had already added the code to the Home page.  It now will not allow me to Edit the page. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi - resolved it but adding append ?contents=1 to the end of the url.  Thanks again.